# Abstracting try/catch with Function in Java 8

Tags: java, eclipse, functional-programming, java-8

I've recently found myself writing many blocks of the following form:

```
try {
    return Optional.of(thing.doSomething(arg));
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    return Optional.empty();
}
```

This is necessary because certain methods signal that they may throw exceptions, and Eclipse yells at me if I don't surround those methods with try/catch blocks.

So I wrote this:

```
public static <A, T> Optional<T> tryOpt (Function<A, T> f, A arg) {
    try {
        return Optional.of(f.apply(arg));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        return Optional.empty();
    }
}
```

So any Function I pass to tryOpt is enclosed in a try/catch block and safely executed, and its result returned as an Optional. But Eclipse still yells at me for using it:

```
return tryOpt(
          ((x) -> thing.doSomething(x)),
          arg);
```

My question is, is there any way for me to tell Eclipse and/or the java compiler that it's okay, and that I *am* indirectly enclosing the offending method within a try/catch block? Or have I just misunderstood something about how java works, in which case, would someone mind enlightening me? Or, on the other hand, can I safely ignore Eclipse's red-line warnings in this case?

Comment: *Eclipse yells at me if I don't surround those methods with try/catch blocks*: no. It yells at you if you don't catch the exception **or throw it**. Returning an empty optional rather than signalling the problem is most probably not the appropriate way of handling the exception. Just throw the exception. Or catch it, wrap it into another exception of the appropriate abstraction level, and throw that new exception. That new exception can be a RuntimeException, if you don't want to force the caller to handle it.

Comment: Catching `Exception` is especially not a good idea: it catches **everything**, including exceptions that you actually don't intend to handle (like NullPointerException, etc.), hiding bugs, and returning incorrect results instead of signalling a problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Function.apply` does not allow to throw an exception, therefore the compiler complains when you pass in a lambda expression which does that.

You can resolve this issue by using a functional interface which allows to throw exceptions. (Maybe such a interface already exists in one of the java.util.* packages):

```
public static <A, T> Optional<T> tryOpt (Fn<A, T> f, A arg) {
    try {
        return Optional.of(f.apply(arg));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        return Optional.empty();
    }
}


public static interface Fn<A, T> {
      T apply(A a) throws Exception;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If it's a red line, it's not a warning, it's an error.

In this case, the `Function<A,R>` interface declares a method that does *not* throw an exception, but your implementation of it does. In this case, your best bet is to create your own functional interface that declares a method that does throw an exception, something like

```
public interface SupplierWithException<R> {R get();}
```

You use it like this:

```
return asOptional(() -> thing.doSomething(arg1, arg2, arg3));
```

However, I would suggest that simply swallowing exceptions is bad form; if you use the `asOptional` method a lot this indicates that you have an impedance mismatch between your sections of your code (a library that you use?). You could either rethrow the exceptions as `RuntimeException`s, or use something like RxJava that explicitly handles exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is how lambdas mixes up with checked exception, the design went in this way which could lead to awkward solutions like wrapping each call to methods which throw inside each lambda in which they are used.

I ended up using a wrapper which manages this for me, something like:

```
  @FunctionalInterface
  public interface FunctionThrowing<T, R>
  {
    R apply(T t) throws Exception;
  }


  public static <T, R> Function<T, R> wrapFunction(FunctionThrowing<T, R> function)
  {
    return a -> {
      try
      {
        return function.apply(a);
      } catch (Exception exception)
      {
        throw exception;
        return null;
      }
    };
  }
```

This basically wraps a function by returning a function which handles the checked exception and converts it to an unchecked exception so that you don't need to wrap each invocation with a `try/catch` block but you still don't lose the ability to catch the exception (since it becomes unchecked).

Comment: "how lambdas mixes up with checked exceptions" -- no, there's no interaction here.  What you're objecting to is that lambdas *don't do anything special for checked exceptions*.  It's just a way of implementing a functional interface.  If the functional interface method lets you throw a given exception, then the lambda can throw that exception, otherwise not.  No different from implementing the functional interface via subclassing.

Answer (score 1):

Modern way of doing it:

```java
interface VoidCallable {
    void call() throws Exception;
}

public static void tryCatchBlockWrapper(VoidCallable func) {
    try {
        func.call();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // do something
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void functionToWrap() {
    tryCatchBlockWrapper(() -> throw new IOException());   
}
```

---

P.S. If you want to add context (pass more arguments) you can just add them:

```java
public static void tryCatchBlockWrapper(String anotherArg, VoidCallable func) {
    // ...
}
```